# java get all values of an array in a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm creating a method to return values of an array. But, I have a problem.

Let's assume the array values are: `771 11 141 1 11 79 7`

arr[0] = 771, arr[1] = 11, arr[2] = 141,...arr[n]

Then, this is my method:

```
public static String split_in_string(int [] an){
    int ans;
    String ansl = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
        ans = an[i];
        ansl = Integer.toString(ans); 
       return ansl;
    }
    return ansl;
}
```

If I use below part in main method:

```
    int ans;
    String ansl = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
        ans = an[i];
        ansl = Integer.toString(ans); 
       System.out.println(ansl+" ");
    }
```

It works well.

But, if I use split_in_string() method, it displays only the first array value.

I expected `771 11 141 1 11 79 7` as the result, but I get only `771`

What's wrong in my split_in_string() method? How can I fix it?

Comment: In split_in_string :
ansl = Integer.toString(ans);
should be replaced with :
ansl += Integer.toString(ans);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to:

```
    public static String split_in_string(int [] an){
        int ans;
        String ansl = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
            ans = an[i];
            ansl = Integer.toString(ans); 
         // return ansl; //commented out this line
            Sysytem.out.println(ansl+" "); //added tjis line
        }
        return ansl;
    }
```

Comment: Downvoted because it merely shifts the error, from returning only the first value `771` to returning only the last value `7`.

Comment: Some values go to standard output, one value is returned...? I'm afraid that your correction is making things even worse.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
public static String split_in_string(int [] an){
    int ans;
    String ansl = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
        ans = an[i];
        ansl += Integer.toString(ans); 
        //return ans1; //commented this line        
    }
    return ansl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ansl += Integer.toString(ans);`. You have to append the values to the same string object.

Try it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
    ans = an[i];
    ansl += Integer.toString(ans); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following also gives you what you want -

```
String str = Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll(",|\\]|\\[", "");
```

e.g.

```
int[] array = {771, 11, 141, 1, 11, 79, 7};
String str = Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll(",|\\]|\\[", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

displays -

```
771 11 141 1 11 79 7
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem it's your first return statement

```
for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
    ans = an[i];
    ansl = Integer.toString(ans); 
    return ansl; // <- This return doesn't allow to continue the loop foor!
}
return ansl;
```

However, you can do this for give you want:

```
String str = Arrays.toString(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two return statements in `use split_in_string` and so you'll return from the first iteration in the loop.

To return all converted strings, create a `List<String>`, add the converted Strings to it, and return that.

```
List<String> split_in_string(int [] an){
   List<String> ansl = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
     ansl.add( Integer.toString(an[i]) ); 
   }
   return ansl;
}
```

OR, all into a single string:

```
String split_in_string(int [] an){
   Stringbuilder ansl = new StringBuilder();
   String del = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
     ansl.append( del ).append( Integer.toString(an[i]) );
     del = " "; 
   }
   return ansl.toString();
}
```

Comment: If you want to have it all in one string, use a string builder and append to it.

Answer (score -1):

It's best not to use that method. If you have a method that works, it's better to stick with that method than using something else that doesn't work out for you. It's faster and time saving, in my opinion, to use this:

```
    int ans;
String ansl = "";
for(int i = 0; i < an.length; i++){
    ans = an[i];
    ansl = Integer.toString(ans); 
   System.out.println(ansl+" ");
}
```

It's what you already have, so it's best to use this method.